# Unknown type name 'QHBoxLayout'

Tags: qt, cmake, qwidget, qlayout, qboxlayout

I'm using QT 6.4.2 at Windows that write App, but when I need to use QHBoxLayout, I get

```
error:Unknown type name 'QHBoxLayout'
```

so I open help document in QT, that found sample about QHBoxLayout, I according to official document create a new project that is very simple:

.pro file is

```
QT       += core gui widgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

HEADERS +=

FORMS +=

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

main.cpp is

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget *window = new QWidget;
    QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("One");
    QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("Two");
    QPushButton *button3 = new QPushButton("Three");
    QPushButton *button4 = new QPushButton("Four");
    QPushButton *button5 = new QPushButton("Five");
    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(window);
    layout->addWidget(button1);
    layout->addWidget(button2);
    layout->addWidget(button3);
    layout->addWidget(button4);
    layout->addWidget(button5);
    window->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Below is some picture at Windows:

[image]

[image]

[image: pro file]

Below is Windows QT version and kit setting:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I try to clean and re-build many times, but it still can't work. I also can't find out what reason cause the problem, so I try to open the same project with QT(6.4.1 version) at MacBook Pro, The same project can surprisingly be compiled successfully and generate executable programs on the Mac platform.

Below is some picture at MacBook Pro:

[image]

[image]

So is that QT latest version's Bug at Windows? How can I solve this problem?

## First update

As @HiFile.app - best file manager said, when I change QHBoxLayout to QVBoxLayout, it seems still can't work when compile, see below picture.

[image]

Now my main.cpp file is :

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget *window = new QWidget;
    QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("One");
    QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("Two");
    QPushButton *button3 = new QPushButton("Three");
    QPushButton *button4 = new QPushButton("Four");
    QPushButton *button5 = new QPushButton("Five");
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(window);
    layout->addWidget(button1);
    layout->addWidget(button2);
    layout->addWidget(button3);
    layout->addWidget(button4);
    layout->addWidget(button5);
    window->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I installed QT through the following method:

[image]

Currently, I have only found issues with QHBoxLayout and QVBoxLayout,  and have not discovered any issues with other controls for the time being.

Where did the problem occur?

## Second update

When I use below command:

```
qmake.exe ChangeFontSize.pro
```

will generate Makefile file.

then I use "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022" to run below command:

```
nmake release
```

for compile also get same error

```
C:\my-win10-document\code\ChangeFontSize>nmake release

Microsoft (R) 程序维护实用工具 14.33.31630.0 版
版权所有 (C) Microsoft Corporation。  保留所有权利。

        C:\my-win10-document\software---install\VS--install\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe -f Makefile.Release

Microsoft (R) 程序维护实用工具 14.33.31630.0 版
版权所有 (C) Microsoft Corporation。  保留所有权利。

        C:\my-win10-document\software---install\QT--install\6.4.2\mingw_64\bin\uic.exe mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
        g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -O2 -std=gnu++1z -Wall -Wextra -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I. -I../../software---install/QT--install/6.4.2/mingw_64/include -I../../software---install/QT--install/6.4.2/mingw_64/include/QtWidgets -I../../software---install/QT--install/6.4.2/mingw_64/include/QtGui -I../../software---install/QT--install/6.4.2/mingw_64/include/QtCore -Irelease -I. -I/include -I../../software---install/QT--install/6.4.2/mingw_64/mkspecs/win32-g++ -o release\main.o main.cpp
        g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -O2 -std=gnu++1z -Wall -Wextra -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I. -I../../software---install/QT--install/6.4.2/mingw_64/include -I../../software---install/QT--install/6.4.2/mingw_64/include/QtWidgets -I../../software---install/QT--install/6.4.2/mingw_64/include/QtGui -I../../software---install/QT--install/6.4.2/mingw_64/include/QtCore -Irelease -I. -I/include -I../../software---install/QT--install/6.4.2/mingw_64/mkspecs/win32-g++ -o release\mainwindow.o mainwindow.cpp
mainwindow.cpp: In constructor 'MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)':
mainwindow.cpp:29:6: error: 'QHBoxLayout' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'QLayout'?
   29 |      QHBoxLayout *hLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |      QLayout
mainwindow.cpp:29:19: error: 'hLayout' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'QLayout'?
   29 |      QHBoxLayout *hLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
      |                   ^~~~~~~
      |                   QLayout
mainwindow.cpp:29:33: error: 'QHBoxLayout' does not name a type; did you mean 'QLayout'?
   29 |      QHBoxLayout *hLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                 QLayout
mainwindow.cpp:34:6: error: 'QVBoxLayout' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'QLayout'?
   34 |      QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |      QLayout
mainwindow.cpp:34:19: error: 'vLayout' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'QLayout'?
   34 |      QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
      |                   ^~~~~~~
      |                   QLayout
mainwindow.cpp:34:33: error: 'QVBoxLayout' does not name a type; did you mean 'QLayout'?
   34 |      QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                 QLayout
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: “C:\my-win10-document\software---install\QT--install\Tools\mingw1120_64\bin\g++.EXE”: 返回代码“0x1”
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: “C:\my-win10-document\software---install\VS--install\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe”: 返回代码“0x2”
Stop.
```

Here is picture:

[image]

## Third update

I created a new project again for test QWidget and QPushButton in Windows platform that can work. See below picture.

[image]

But when I only new add two line code in main.cpp (No changes have been made elsewhere), then compile will get error, see below picture:

[image]

So far, I have confirmed that using QHBoxLayout and QVBoxLayout is problematic.

Comment: This is a very strange bug, I have never encountered such a problem - and I am using Qt 6.4.2 too for a widget application without any issues. So maybe a stupid suggestion: did you try to re-run qmake for your project? 

Btw. the About box for your QtCreator does show the version with which your QtCreator was built and does not show your actual Qt framework version. Are you sure you are using 6.4.2? Check Projects settings to see the version and check Preferences->Kits if your paths are correct.

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager I have try to clean and re-rebuild many times,but still doesn't work. I'm sure I use QT 6.4.2 at windows(See above picture). I will update my question that show Preferences->Kits if my paths are correct.

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager Can you find out where is problem? Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: I am afraid, I have no idea what may be wrong. You can try other Qt version (e.g. the latest LTS version 6.2.4) or MSVC version (but it will require to install MS build tools). I have never used MinGW tools on Windows, so I have no experience with them...

Comment: Is the problem only with `QHBoxLayout`? What happens if you change `QHBox...` to `QVBox...`? Will that work? (I am not suggesting that you redefine your layouts, I am just trying to diagnose the problem)

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager ,I update my question as you said change QHBoxLayout to QVBoxLayout, it seems still can't work when compile.

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager Currently, I have only found issues with QHBoxLayout and QVBoxLayout, and have not discovered any issues with other controls for the time being. I create that project(officical sample) just check QVBoxLayout and QHBoxLayout if work ok.

Comment: If you create a new project (the sample which you show without VBoxLayout) and then compare the generated .pro file with the .pro file shich you have for your project with QVBoxLayout... are there any differences? What is you try to include and use `QVBoxLyaout` in the new project? Will it work? What happens if you move include <QVBoxLayout> to the very top above <QApplication>? Still the same problem? (sorry, these might sound stupid, but these are just diagnostics checks which might help)

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager According to the method you mentioned, so far, I have confirmed that using QHBoxLayout and QVBoxLayout is problematic. See my question update about "Third update". I test heard file #include <QVBoxLayout> placed in the first line or the second line or the third line,it don't matter(or it is not important), still get error when compile.

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager I solved the problem by reinstalling QT by myself, and now it can be used normally. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by reinstalling QT by myself, and now it can be used normally.

[image]

Comment: Oh, I thought this was something that you had already tried. Otherwise I would have suggested it as the very first step.

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager I should first try to reinstall QT.